error with the path to import GLTF loader on threeJs
I had a problem who persist with a test project with three js...
i made my 3d models on blender anbd export him to .glb format and now try to imoport it to my scene with GLTF Loader but always the same error on the console.
this is my html :
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>My first three.js app</title>
   <script type="module">
       window.onload = () => {
           const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
           canvas.width = window.innerWidth / 4;
           canvas.height = window.innerHeight / 2;
       }
   </script>
   <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Salut</h1>
   <div id="canvasPlace">
       <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
   </div>
</body>
</html>

this is my js :
import * as THREE from '/node_modules/three/build/three.module.js'
import { GLTFLoader } from '/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/Addons.js';

const scene = new THREE.Scene()

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, innerWidth / innerHeight)

const loader = new GLTFLoader();

loader.load( '/models/logoFini.glb', function ( gltf ) {

    scene.add( gltf.scene );

}, undefined, function ( error ) {

    console.error( error );

} );

camera.position.set(0, 0, 4)

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas })

loop()
function loop() {
    requestAnimationFrame(loop)
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.01
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
}


and this is my console error :
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
I upload my folder architecture too :
folder architecture
i Think the solution is in the path to import my gltf loader but idk how too fix it...
i try the path from the THREEjs docs but nothing happend

Look here
